# Oops! Something Bad Happened! - Can't login

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, users, google-openid

Created an account with my gmail and a random password on stackoverflow on 2012 and used a lot until 2013.

After a gap of a few years I'm back and since there was a more convenient "Login with Google" button I used it.

The problem is that I lost all my data, badges, profile and so on.

How to recover that if when I go to the "forgot your password" page it tells me only "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"?

Comment: Which account is this?

Comment: It is best to use the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page and share in private the details with the team that are needed to get this rectified. Not much we can do here in public.

Comment: Perfect. I was lead here by the instructions of the own site. But I'll try to contact support.